# Office 365 license not assigned using new-msoluser

Tags: powershell, office365

I have a Powershell (5.0) script that imports a CSV file and creates new Office 365 users. The accounts are being created correctly, however the specified license is not being applied.

My script:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\tmp9DBC.csv | %{ New-MsolUser -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -City $_.City -Country $_.Country -Department $_.Department -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName -ForceChangePassword:$True -UsageLocation $_.Location -Password $_.Password -PasswordNeverExpires:$True -State $_.State -Title $_.Title -LicenseAssignment $_.License}
```

All other properties are assigned correctly, but all of my users show `isLicensed = false`.

Assigning the license manually works fine, so I know that the SKU is good. Why is it not being applied?

**EDIT:** Sample entry from CSV file as requested:

```
ADULTMAN Vincent,adultmanv@domain.onmicrosoft.com,MyCity,MyCountry,Library and Information Services,Vincent,Adultman,"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:STANDARDWOFFPACK_IW_FACULTY",Jaom3231,WA,Library Assistant
```

Comment: What is the value of `License` variable  while assigning it? and also can you share a sample record that you are using in your csv file?

Comment: Aw jeez...once I read your comment I reviewed the CSV file. Turns out that the `License` column was named `AccountType` instead. *headdesk* Thanks for nudging me in the right direction. Sometimes, all it takes is an extra pair of eyeballs. Please write an answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is resolved. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `Import-Csv` power shell command you must make sure that you are using the same column name which are mentioned in the csv file.

As your csv file contains column `AccountType` for licensing details, so please replace your existing powershell command with this:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\tmp9DBC.csv | %{ New-MsolUser -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -City $_.City -Country $_.Country -Department $_.Department -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName -ForceChangePassword:$True -UsageLocation $_.Location -Password $_.Password -PasswordNeverExpires:$True -State $_.State -Title $_.Title -LicenseAssignment $_.AccountType}
```

Hope this will help you.